# running ps command on multiple machine using python script in unix

Tags: python, unix, ssh, ps

My machines are `MachineA, MachineB, MachineC, MachineD, MachineE`.
In unix if i do `ssh MachineA` , it will login into `MachineA`.

In Python if i run `os.system("ssh MachineA")` it will login to this machine and exists, you will see the changed machine on your vnc.

I want to write a script , that will login into machine and it will run ps command and some extracting data, then it has to change machine to MachineB and above thing as to repeated to all machines.

```
machine_list.txt contains
MachineA
MachineB
MachineC
MachineD
MachineE
```

MY Script:

```
fle=open('machine_list.txt ','r')
for line in fle:
   command="ssh "+line
   os.system(command)
   os.system("ps -aux | tee ps_output.txt")
   fl=open('ps_output.txt','r')
   for line1 in fl:
      print line1
```

But in this `os.system(command)` is executing and it will comeout from script.

```
os.system("ps -aux | tee ps_output.txt")
fl=open('ps_output.txt','r')
for line1 in fl:
    print line1
```

These line wont execute.

Is any other way to dont change the original machine in my vnc? the above one changing the machine and that will affect your vnc, but i dont want this
I need only the information about processes which are running on each machine.
Please tell me how can i do this.

I need like cd command done using `os.chdir("directory_name")`,how it doesnt affect the shell, like is any way to do with ssh?
Please any suggestion?

Comment: don't use os.system. Use subprocess or pexpect and redirect output to the text file

Comment: hi, its not working, i dont have authority to install new packages , i have to write script using existing packages of python. please help me.

Comment: Hi Padraic , Thanks for replaying, i am not getting how to use subprocess for this ssh and ps command , i am new to python . so can you tell how can i do this, please let me know.